# Configure Spring JNDI datasource with DBCP and connection parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, jndi, cloudbees, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using Spring 3 and attempting to use a JNDI (named) data source with DBCP connection pooling.

I would like to be able to set pool parameters, but my

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
</bean>
```

doesn't support the necessary params:

```
<!-- Connection Pool settings -->
<param name="maxActive" value="5" />
<param name="maxIdle" value="2" />
<param name="maxWait" value="10000" />
<param name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
<param name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />
<param name="logAbandoned" value="true" />

<!-- Purge invalid connections -->
<param name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
<param name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
```

I've googled this extensively, and it looks like it's expected that the container (tomcat) should set these kinds of params for JNDI connections, not the application.

Unfortunately in my situation (cloudbees) I don't have control over tomcat.

Is what I'm attempting even possible?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've figured out how to do this. For reference, you need to use the Cloudbees SDK's bindings feature:

```
bees app:bind -a APP_ID -db DB_ID -as DATASOURCE_NAME maxActive=5 maxIdle=2 \
maxWait=10000 removeAbandoned=true removeAbandonedTimeout=60 logAbandoned=true \
validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow=true
```